# Lich + Laboratory maniac, replacement effects order

Tags: magic-the-gathering

You have [Lich](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=202483) and [Laboratory Maniac](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Laboratory%20Maniac) in play, 3 cards in your deck, and you play [Solemn Offering](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Solemn%20Offering) or [Serene Offering](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Serene%20Offering) on Lich (either one will heal 4 in this case). Do you win or lose?

Comment: Do you mean Serene Offering or Solemn Offering? Divine Offering can't target Lich.

Comment: @diego I've replaced the mention of Divine Offering with Serene and Solemn Offering. Conveniently enough, they'll both heal for 4 in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You will lose.

As the Offering is resolving you follow the instructions in order, thus first you destroy the Lich, then you gain life. Since Lich is no longer on the battlefield its replacement effect doesn't apply so you will not draw cards instead of gaining life. Then once the Offering is done resolving the Lich's leaves the battlefield trigger will go on the stack and you will lose the game when it resolves.

> **608.2c** The controller of the spell or ability follows its instructions in the order written. However, replacement effects may modify these actions.

Comment: Thanks, indeed I forgot the text of divine offering was resolving the liche destruction completely before resolving the heal 4 hp part, hence no more lich replacement effect when the heal happens.